# Issue with py2exe executable on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: python, windows, pyside, py2exe

I have 3 identical (I thought) servers that are running 2012 R2. I built the app using python 3.4 and PySide 1.2.4 on a Windows 7 machine. Running the setup file gives me the executable as well as 3 dll files: QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, and QtNetwork4,dll. I copied all these files to the 3 servers. I can run the exe from 2 of the servers just fine, but the third one is giving me trouble. At first it was giving me an error saying that MSVCR100.dll was not installed. So, I copied msvcr100.dll from one of the other servers where the exe runs fine. Now when I try to run the exe I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ninja_Lite.py", line 3, in 
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zipextimporter.py", line 109, in load_module
ImportError: MemoryLoadLibrary failed loading PySide\QtGui.pyd: The specified module could not be found. (126)

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error to only happen on one of the 3 servers?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the issue. There were some differences in the MSVCP and MSVCR dll files between the 2 machines. I copied all the missing dll files from the machine that was working to the one that wasn't both in the System32 and SysWOW64 directories and now the program is working.

The files were:
msvcp60.dll
msvcp100.dll
mscvp120.dll
msvcr60.dll
msvcr100.dll
msvcr120.dll

Hope this helps anyone in the future!

Comment: Don't just copy these dlls, these are Microsoft C++ runtimes. Install them from Microsoft.